# One XML file is correct, the other is destroyed? - Same function? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I wrote a function which is deleting all `<product>...</product>` nodes where the title is not matching with one title in my title array filter.

My problem is, that 4 XML files gets saved and modified right and also saved but one XML file is getting completely destroyed...

After I called that function on this XML sheet I just see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products/>
```

Before modifying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <title>METRO</title>
    <price>10.99</price>
    <platform>Steam</platform>
  </product>
  <product>
    <title>XBOX Live Gold</title>
    <price>46.99</price>
    <platform>Xbox</platform>
  </product>
</products>
```

This is my function:

```
function filterGames($dom){
    $xpathQuery = "/products/product";
    $xp = new DomXpath($dom);
    $items = $xp->query($xpathQuery);

    echo "(filterGames) Delete Games\n";

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
        if (!(array_search(mb_strtolower($title), array_map('mb_strtolower', $GLOBALS["titleArray"])))) {
        //if (!(in_array($title, $GLOBALS["titleArray"]))) {
            $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
            echo "Removed: " . $title ."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody has an idea why 4 XML files get saved and modified right but one file is totally destroyed?

I also swaped the order in which the XML files get modified by the filter but it doesn't made an change. Again, the other 4 files get saved and modified right but one is destroyed. And it is always the same XML file which is destroyed!

I also enter the if condition because I see that with `echo`. But anyway... The file is destroyed.

*Edit:*
Here are two other examples of my XML sheets before and after modified by `filterGames`. They look exactly the same like the destroyed XML file before modified by `filterGames`

XML File 1 before modified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <price>11.69</price>
    <price_base>12.99</price_base>
    <title>Final Fantasy VII</title>
  </product>
<products>
```

XML File 1 after modified looks exactly like bevor modified except that some nodes have been delete because they are not matching the `$GLOBALS["titleArray"]`filter.

XML File 2 before modified:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <title>Battlefield 2</title>
    <price>5.95</price>
  </product>
<products>
```

XML File 2 after modified looks exactly like bevor modified except that some nodes have been delete because they are not matching the `$GLOBALS["titleArray"]`filter.

---

**I found an interesting fact!**
My XML file which is getting destroyed after filtered by `filterGames()` is meanwhile not the only XML file which is getting destroyed. And both files where converted by my `csvToXML(...)` function from CSV to XML. So I think the reason must be this! - Because all other XMLs files don't get converted!

```
function csvToXML($inputFilename, $outputFilename, $delimiter = ',')
{
  // Open csv to read
  $inputFile = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

  // Get the headers of the file
  $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter);

  // Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
  $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $doc->formatOutput = true;

  // Add a root node to the document
  $root = $doc->createElement('products');
  $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

  // Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
  while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
    $container = $doc->createElement('product');
    foreach ($headers as $i => $header) {
      $child = $doc->createElement($header);
      $child = $container->appendChild($child);
      $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
      $value = $child->appendChild($value);
    }

    $root->appendChild($container);
  }

  $strxml = $doc->saveXML();
  $handle = fopen($outputFilename, 'w');
  fwrite($handle, $strxml);
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What is the value in the $GLOBALS["titleArray"]? Also you might want to add the other xml file that are working.

Comment: The function you are seeing there `filterGames()` is there is a function in my function.php file. There are also other functions declared and because I need a some variables in different functions I decided to make them Global in my function.php. Don't worry about that! I will add 2 other examples. But do not wondering. They look exactly like the destroyed XML File before modifying!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it should work:

```
<?php

function filterGames($dom) {
    $xpathQuery = "/products/product";
    $xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $items = $xp->query($xpathQuery);

    // convert the array since this can be one time
    $titles = array_map('mb_strtolower', $GLOBALS['titleArray']);

    // loop over the products in the xml
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // convert the title to lowercase
        $title = mb_strtolower($item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent);

        // check if the title is not in the array of titles
        // if not in the arr, then remove it
        if(!in_array($title, $titles)) {
          $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
          echo "Removed: " . $title ."\n";
          // there needs to be a save call here
        }
    }
}

// array of titles
$GLOBALS['titleArray'] = array("METRO");

// load the xml document
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("input.xml");

// call the function
filterGames($dom);
```

The problem is that `array_search()` returns the key and not a boolean. So if the key is >= 1, then it would be converted to true and anything else would be a false. So there were probably false positives causing the products to be removed.

Comment: I will test it in a few hrs :)

Comment: Still same output... :/ - I don't see the error... Is there another way? - Simple XML or DOM?

Comment: There is no error. I modified the if statement to use `in_array()` instead of `array_search()`. `array_search()` returns the first successful key if found. That is what is causing the different results. You should change it to use `in_array()` which will return a boolean value for the if statement.

Comment: I don't think that it will change something... Take a look at my update!

Comment: I dont see where in your new code you are calling `filterGames()`. So this is an entirely new question now.

Comment: Okay, I will make a new question. Which title? -> Are CSV converted XML files not "real" XML files?

Comment: Something like that. Also make sure to provide same files too.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Make sure you add a csv file as an example of the data you are using.

Comment: I will do. Thank you!